# Spring is not showing validation error for Dynamically generated Form Id

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, data-binding, spring-form

Spring validation works fine for a form with static id. But in my scenario forms are generated dynamically on frontend.

For Example - My form bean is - GenericQuestionnaireForm so if i have the form element as below

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="genericQuestionnaireForm" action="/save-generic-questionnaire">
```

validation works fine and the errors are correctly displayed.

But I have to capture the form values for different products so I am generating different forms with unique id by attaching the form name with the product number.

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="product1_genericQuestionnaireForm"  action="/save-generic-questionnaire">
```

when I submit this form to my controller method the BindingResult are getting attached to the genericQuestionnaireForm form object due to which the errors are not getting displayed on front end.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-generic-questionnaire", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveQuestionnaire(@Valid final GenericQuestionnaireForm genericQuestForm,final BindingResult bindingResult,  final Model model,
                                    final RedirectAttributes redirectModel, final HttpServletRequest request) throws CMSItemNotFoundException{

    if(genericQuestForm != null) {

        genericQuestionnaireFormValidator.validate(genericQuestForm, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) 
        {  return //to the front end..}
}
```

My query is - Is there a way to attach the BindingResult to the dynamic form Id in order to show the generated errors. Or is there a better way to do form validation in this scenario?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't include the product name as a form field?

Comment: The requirement is to show all the filled form data per product to user at the same time and we are able to populate these forms after saving it which is working fine. But the problem I am getting is when user edit one form and it fails the validation spring does not associate the BindingError to the generated for Id instead it associate it with the FormBean which is ( genericQuestionnaireForm ) in this case.

Comment: Have you tryed to change the `modelAttribute` name to `genericQuestForm` so that it match the command name?

Comment: I tried with @ModelAttribute("genericQuestForm") and changing it to match it with the form id being submitted from front end like @ModelAttribute("332400_genericQuestionnaireForm") but still the validation errors are not showing on the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<<form:form:form method="post" modelAttribute="genericQuestionnaireForm" action="/save-generic-questionnaire" >
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
.................
</form:form>
```

modelAttribute attribute always remains the same.

```
@ModelAttribute("genericQuestionnaireForm")
public genericQuestionnaireForm getgenericQuestionnaireForm(){
    return new genericQuestionnaireForm();
}

RequestMapping(value = "/save-generic-questionnaire", method =   
RequestMethod.POST)

public String saveQuestionnaire(@Valid final GenericQuestionnaireForm genericQuestForm, BindingResult bindingResult.....
```

for identifing different products just use hidden id.